# If a Random Forest scores high accuracy on test set, but high false negative on real-world application, is this an overfit?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, random-forest, cart, hyperparameter

I'm very new to Machine Learning and I'm making a Random Forest Classifier to classify if a file is a malware or benign. This is done through analyzing the PE file's headers. **The dataset used contains approximately 40k clean file data and 90k malware file data**. I put the n_estimators to 1000, but this is the only hyperparameter that I added. I'm using sklearn's train_test_split to split the data into train and test data. After fitting the model and outputting the accuracy using accuracy_score(), I get 0.99% on both train and test. But later found out after using the model to predict some malicious and legit .exe that the model will almost always predict the legit .exe files (mostly installers) as malware.

After some more digging, I'm still confused whether it's caused by:

1. Overfitting? (I'm thinking this is likely since the accuracy is too good to be true)
2. Imbalanced dataset?
3. Need more hyperparameter tweaking for the Random Forest Classifier (maybe the tree depth is too deep)?
4. Bad dataset?

Comment: I assume it has 99% accuracy, not 0.99%. So, it doesn't predict all malware in your test set, but it does so in the second test set, is that right? This sounds like the two datasets do not come from same/similar distributions.

Comment: Oh yeah it's 99%, my bad. Both train and test produced 99% accuracy. I then run some clean and malware .exe files and it predicted ALL of the malwares right, but for the clean files, most of the time it predicts it as malware (high false negative when applied to real world files). Is there anything I can do to mitigate/ reduce this? I am currently doing a grid search for the hyperparameters hoping to reduce this.

Comment: Data drift/concept drift. ;)